# Proving $x^{2}+1 \neq n! $,using Gaussian Integer.

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, proof-writing, solution-verification

I want to show that
$$x^{2}+1 \neq n! $$ for $n>3$ where $x,n$ are both integers.

Since $$x^{2}+1=(x+i)(x-i) $$ it follows that $x^{2}+1$ has only prime factors on the form ($4k+1$), whereas $n!$ has prime factors of the form ($4k-1$) and ($4k+1$).

Refs: [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares), [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity), [Gaussian integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer)

Is it (the way I proposed the proof) correct?
 
**The proof is my concern rather than the solution of the problem. There are other ways to prove the problem/statement,  pleases comment on my proof only.**

**Motivation** Regular facts might have different interpretation, which is essential to learn mathematics.

Comment: ... and the question is?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : See tags.

Comment: $0^2 + 1 = 1 = 1! = 0!$ and $1^2 + 1 = 2 = 2!$, so already we have some solutions of the form $(x,n)$ being $(0,0), (0,1), (1,2)$

Comment: I should mention as well that it is **very important** to mention what $x$ and $n$ are allowed to be.  If you allow $x$ to be any **real number**, then trivially there are infinitely many pairs and your claim isn't true.  You can have $x=\sqrt{n!-1}$ whatever $n$ is (e.g. for $n=5$ you have $x=\sqrt{119}$).  In the problem statement you need to specify that $x$ must be an integer or natural number, that $n$ is a natural number and that $n>2$ to make the claim true.

Comment: All integer solutions to $x^2=n!+1$ is an open problem ([Brocard's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem)). But this one  is easily solvable.

Comment: This is a very elementary statement you want to prove and therefore imo it should have a detailed proof. If you want to prove it with your method I think you you should 1) prove why $x^2+1 = (x+i)(x-i)$ implies that $x$ has only prime factors on the form $4k+1$. You could perhaps reference a theorem for this. 2) Write more detailed in what cases $n!$ has prime-factors on the form  $4k-1$ and state that this contradicts $x^2+1=n!$. You also need to handle special cases (i.e. $n=1,2$). As you will see, this makes the proof much more involved than it need to be (compared to the answers below)

Comment: The proof is kind of vague since it says that $n!$ has factors of the form $4k-1$. It would be better to just pick one, say $3$. In picking $3$, we see that $n\ge3$ is needed. Now you can use the fact that $3$ is a Gaussian prime to show that if $3\mid(x-i)(x+i)$, then $3\mid x-i$ or $3\mid x+1$, neither of which can be true.

Answer (score 7):

If $n\ge 4$, then $n!$ is divisible by $4$, but $x^2+1$ cannot be. For $n=3$, $6$ is not of the form $x^2+1$. $n=0, 1, 2$ were addressed in a comment above.

Comment: The proof is my concern rather than the solution of the problem , plesase comment on that.

Comment: Noting that $x^2+1\not\equiv0\pmod3$ is just about as easy and covers the case $n=3$.

Comment: @robjohn Good point.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x^2-1=n!-2$, Assuming we are dealing with integers, the following is elementary.

The right-hand side of this is even for $n\ge 2$ and is divisible by $2$ but not $4$ for $n\ge 4$ (because  then $n!$ is divisible by $4$).

This means that to make the left-hand side even $x$ must be odd, but then $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$ is the product of two successive even numbers and hence is divisible by $8$. And this is a contradiction.

The small cases can be checked by hand, and yield some solutions as others have shown.

Comment: The proof is my concern rather than the solution of the problem , plesase comment on that.